# Как дождаться завершения всех потоков в программе .NET

Tags: c#, .net, visual-basic

В программе имеется три таймера, два таймера типа `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` по тикам апдейтят информацию из базы и сервисов,  один типа `System.Timers.Timer` посылает запросы на сервис и пишет в базу данные. Все они создают разные потоки, и при попытке закрыть форму как правило вылетает исключение что поток еще не отработал. Как при попытке закрытия формы узнать какие потоки кроме основного еще пытаются работать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Thread trThread = new Thread(()=>{});
trThead.Start();
trThread.IsAlive;
```

свойство показывающее, не завершился ли еще поток.

Upd:

```
  internal class Program
    {
        #region Private Fields

        private static Timer timer = new Timer(DoCall, new object(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

        #endregion Private Fields

        #region Private Methods

        private static void DoCall(object state)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            //вот тут я хватаю текущий поток за хвост и вывожу его Id.
            Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            //В вашем сценарии я бы в начале метода инкрементировал число запущенных "задач" а в конце декриментировал. И когда число будет = 0, значит все отработало. 
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("-");
            Console.ReadKey();
            timer.Dispose(); //тики закончились, ждем обнуления Count
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        #endregion Private Methods
    }
```

Надо понимать, что тут не гарантировано, но убрано до минимального значения вероятность получить ту ошибку.
В чем суть. Есть тик, время на выполнение которого однозначно больше времени между тиками. создаем счетчик "задач", в начале метода делаем ему ++, а по завершению --.
Далее, когда хотим выйти Dispose на таймере и ждем обнуления счетчика задач. После чего — выход.

Comment: какое это имеет отношение к потокам которые создают таймеры? я в таймерах не создаю вручную потоки, они их сами создают при каждом тике.

Comment: То есть код выполняется в событии `Private Sub Timer2_Tick` он уже автоматом выполняется в другом потоке.

Comment: Зависит от того, какой именно таймер. Тогда обрисуйте задачу конкретнее. Почему именно таймер для вас является отправной точкой? Чем примитивы синхронизации вам не подходят? Т.е. инизиализируете флаг IsOperationComplite = false. А потом в потоке таймера IsOperationComplite = true последней опирацией. Конечно, все под lock-ом.

Comment: Поток таймера получить тоже можно. Но это отдельная тема.

Comment: дело в том что из того что вы мне написали я не понял ни одного слова(

Comment: Опишите сперва зачем вам таймер, так будет легче посказывать

Comment: в описании вопроса написано зачем таймеры...

Comment: Хорошо. Давай с начала. при поднятии clr стартует сразу несколько потоков, обеспечивающих работу и их колличество может меняться. К примеру, gc отрабатывает в своем потоке собирая мусор, строя деревья и т.п. Потому общее число незавершенных потоков — не скажет ни о чем правильном. Тут проще плясать от таймеров. К примеру — отключать их при закрытии формы. Если же и это не помогает, то Dispose.

Comment: Отключение таймеров ничего не даст если не знать сколько потоков ушло в обработку и когда они завершат работу. прерывать потоки нельзя ибо они должны отработать и выполнить фоновую задачу. При старте winform приложения стартует один основной поток вообще то, это указано в мсдн.

Comment: Зачем им дорабатывать если потребитель (форма) закрывается?